# Complex Servlet relationships... Is it possible?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameter-passing

I'm wondering how can I pass parameters between 2 servlets. But it is kinda different... Let me more specific. I have a Login page and users in DB with their passwords. If user created by manager has not have a password. User enters only username and click Login then creationpassword page will come. Then user who just created a password will automatically login succesfully. (Here is the thing. I do not want user to re-type his username and password "just created" again to LOGIN.) when he is done creation passwords then he can be redirected to desired page. But pageforwards servlet is first servlet. Let me more clear.

My servlets are LoginServlet(actioned from loginPage.jsp), CreatePassServlet(actioned from createPass.jsp).

When user enters his username LoginServlet checks his password(it is exist or not) then if not forwards it with username to createPass.jsp page then user enters his password then CreatePassServlet creates his password and stores in DB then go back with his username and password informations to LoginServlet(which is directs him to desired page)

Here my classes...

LoginServlet

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public LoginServlet() {
    super();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        int pEmployeeId;
        String pName;
        String pSurname;
        String pUserName;
        String pUserType;
        String query;
        String home = "/login.jsp";
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(home);
        mysqlCon con = new mysqlCon();
        LoginService ls = new LoginService();


        if((password==null) || (password=="")){

            Statement stmt = con.getConnection().createStatement();
            query = "SELECT password FROM employee WHERE username='"
                    + username + "';";
            stmt.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            if(rs.next()){

                String nextJSP = "createPassword.jsp";
                rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                rd.forward(request, response);      

                return;
            }

        }


        String getHashedPass = Md5HashPassword.Md5(password);

        Statement stmt = con.getConnection().createStatement();
        query = "SELECT employee_id, name, surname, usertype, username FROM employee WHERE username='"
                + username + "' AND password='" + getHashedPass + "';";
        stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();

        if (rs.next()) {
            pEmployeeId = rs.getInt(1);
            pName = rs.getString(2);
            pSurname = rs.getString(3);
            pUserType = rs.getString(4);
            pUserName = rs.getString(5);

            if (ls.loginCheck(username, getHashedPass) != false) {
                Person tmp = new Person();

                tmp.setName(pName);
                tmp.setSurname(pSurname);
                tmp.setType(pUserType);
                tmp.setUsername(pUserName);
                tmp.setId((long) pEmployeeId);
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("person", tmp);

                if (pUserType.equals(UserType.MANAGER.toString())) {

                    String nextJSP = "managerHome.jsp";
                    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }

                else if (pUserType.equals(UserType.ADMIN.toString())) {

                    String nextJSP = "adminHome.jsp";
                    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                    rd.forward(request, response);

                }

                else if (pUserType.equals(UserType.USER.toString())) {

                    String nextJSP = "userHome.jsp";
                    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                } else {

                    String nextJSP = "login.jsp";
                    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }

            }
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage",
                    "Login Failed. Your username or password is incorrect. ");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }

        con.getConnection().close();

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

}
```

CreatePassServlet...

```
public class CreatePassServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public CreatePassServlet() {
    super();    
}




protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    mysqlCon con=new mysqlCon();
    String password=request.getParameter("password");
    String passwordcheck=request.getParameter("passwordcheck");

    if(password.equals(passwordcheck)){

        try {
            String query;
            String hashedPass = Md5HashPassword.Md5(password);      
            String username=request.getParameter("username");

            Statement stmt = con.getConnection().createStatement();
            query = "UPDATE employee SET password='"+ hashedPass +"' WHERE username='"+ username +"';";
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

            request.setAttribute("username", username);
            ServletContext sc = getServletContext();  
            RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/LoginServlet");  
            rd.forward(request, response);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    else{
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("createPassword.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage",
                "Creation failed. Your passwords did not match, please try again. ");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }






}





protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}
```

}

Pages are correct... I'm getting this when I run it...

When i try to back loginservlet to continue, CreatePassServlet redirects Username as NULL and my password. I guess the point is I cant pass my username back to LoginServlet again. Then I'm getting login username - password wrong error from loginServlet because username is NULL.

Please help me out here. Thanks in advance...

Comment: And before you go on with servlet coding: NEVER COMPARE STRINGS IN JAVA WITH ==

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that you are probably not setting `hashedPass` in the request object!

You could save the information at many places. One such place is the your httpsession.

```
session.setAttribute("newPassword", param);
```

In Servlets you have 3 scopes where you can store data.

> Application
>
> Session
>
> Request

Additionally, JSP has `page` scope to save data.

Please see http://www.fcet.staffs.ac.uk/gdm1/general/java/web/servlets/scopes.asp for a quick overview on how to use these scope to save data and pass on to other servlets.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, you might think to accept the answer.

Comment: actually I couldn't find how can i solve... And I tried to user re-type his username and password again but this time password couldnt be store in db so getting username and pass wrong error

Comment: What is the exception in saving into DB?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your code, when you execute LoginServlet **after** CreatePassServlet you must look for username using request.getAttribute("username").toString();

try something like:

```
        String username = (request.getAttribute("username")==null)?
request.getParameter("b"):request.getAttribute("username").toString();
```

instead of:

```
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
```